# How to display the exact age in Year Month Day format in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I am stuck with my query. I have a table called `Patient`. In this table a column has patient `DOB`. Actually I want to display the **exact** age of the patient.

For example:

```
PatName   DOB (MM/dd/yyyy)   Age
a         06/02/1947         65 Years 1 Month/s 3 Days 
b         07/10/1947         64 Years 11 Month/s 25 Days 
c         -----------        -----------------------
```

I want to display the age of the above format.

I have already googled about this but nobody helped.

If you have any query regarding this pls post that.

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
DATEDIFF(year, DOB, getdate()) - (CASE WHEN (DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, DOB, getdate()), DOB)) > getdate() THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Years, 
MONTH(getdate() - (DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, DOB, getdate()), DOB))) - 1 as Month/s, 
DAY(getdate() - (DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, DOB, getdate()), DOB))) - 1 as Days
```

Comment: When date of birth is '20170131' and current date is '20170301' it returns wrong value 0 0 29 instead of 0 1 1

Answer (score 3):

Hi Check the query below.

```
--DROP TABLE patient
CREATE TABLE patient(PatName varchar(100),DOB date,  Age varchar(100))
INSERT INTO patient
VALUES('a','06/02/1947',NULL),('b','07/10/1947',NULL),('c','12/21/1982',NULL)

;WITH CTE(PatName,DOB,years,months,days) AS 
(SELECT PatName,DOB,DATEDIFF(yy,DOB,getdate()),DATEDIFF(mm,DOB,getdate()),DATEDIFF(dd,DOB,getdate()) FROM patient)

--SELECT * FROM CTE

SELECT PatName,DOB,
      CAST(months/12 as varchar(5))+' Years'+CAST((months % 12) as varchar(5))+' month/s '+CAST(CASE WHEN DATEADD(MM,(months % 12),DATEADD(YY,(months/12),DOB)) <= GETDATE() then DATEDIFF(dd,DATEADD(MM,(months % 12),DATEADD(YY,(months/12),DOB)),GETDATE()) ELSE DAY(getdate()) END as varchar(5))+' days' as Age

FROM CTE
```

Comment: Hi Anand, As I observe the query It calculates exact age of some rows not for all rows. I think this is not perfect answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you follow [this link](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=62729), you'll find a function doing exactly that:

```
create function dbo.F_AGE_YYYY_MM_DD
    (
    @START_DATE     datetime,
    @END_DATE       datetime
    )
returns  varchar(10) 
as
/*
Function: F_AGE_YYYY_MM_DD

This function calculates age in years, months and days
from @START_DATE through @END_DATE and
returns the age in format YYYY MM DD.

Years is the number of full years between @START_DATE and @END_DATE.

Months is the number of full months since the last full year anniversary.

Days is the number of days since the last full month anniversary.

*/
begin

declare @AGE varchar(10)

declare @AGE_IN_YEARS       int
declare @AGE_IN_MONTHS  int
declare @AGE_IN_DAYS        int

-- Return null if @START_DATE > @END_DATE
if @START_DATE > @END_DATE begin return @AGE end

select
    @AGE_IN_YEARS = AGE_IN_YEARS,
    @AGE_IN_MONTHS = AGE_IN_MONTHS,
    @AGE_IN_DAYS =
        datediff(dd,
        dateadd(mm,AGE_IN_MONTHS,
        dateadd(yy,AGE_IN_YEARS,START_DATE))
        ,END_DATE)
from
(
select
    AGE_IN_MONTHS =
    case
    when AnniversaryThisMonth <= END_DATE
    then datediff(mm,dateadd(yy,AGE_IN_YEARS,START_DATE),END_DATE)
    else datediff(mm,dateadd(yy,AGE_IN_YEARS,START_DATE),END_DATE)-1
    end,
    *
from
(
select
    AGE_IN_YEARS =
    case
    when AnniversaryThisYear <= END_DATE
    then datediff(yy,START_DATE,END_DATE)
    else datediff(yy,START_DATE,END_DATE)-1
    end,
    *
from
(
select
    AnniversaryThisYear =
    dateadd(yy,datediff(yy,START_DATE,END_DATE),START_DATE),
    AnniversaryThisMonth =
    dateadd(mm,datediff(mm,START_DATE,END_DATE),START_DATE),
    *
from
(
select  START_DATE  = dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,@START_DATE),0),
    END_DATE    = dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0,@END_DATE),0)
) aaaa
) aaa
) aa
) a

select @AGE =
    right('0000'+convert(varchar(4),@AGE_IN_YEARS),4) + ' ' +
    right('00'+convert(varchar(4),@AGE_IN_MONTHS),2) + ' ' +
    right('00'+convert(varchar(4),@AGE_IN_DAYS),2)

return @AGE

end
go

select [Age] = dbo.F_AGE_YYYY_MM_DD('2004-04-07','2006-02-03')

select [Age] = dbo.F_AGE_YYYY_MM_DD('2006-02-03','2006-02-03')

select [Age] = dbo.F_AGE_YYYY_MM_DD('2006-02-05','2006-02-03')

select [Age] = dbo.F_AGE_YYYY_MM_DD('1950-09-13', getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @date datetime, @tmpdate datetime, @years int, @months int, @days int
SELECT @date = '06/02/1947'

SELECT @tmpdate = @date

SELECT @years = DATEDIFF(yy, @tmpdate, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN (MONTH(@date) > MONTH(GETDATE())) OR (MONTH(@date) = MONTH(GETDATE()) AND DAY(@date) > DAY(GETDATE())) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
SELECT @tmpdate = DATEADD(yy, @years, @tmpdate)
SELECT @months = DATEDIFF(m, @tmpdate, GETDATE()) - CASE WHEN DAY(@date) > DAY(GETDATE()) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
SELECT @tmpdate = DATEADD(m, @months, @tmpdate)
SELECT @days = DATEDIFF(d, @tmpdate, GETDATE())

print cast(@years as varchar(4)) + ' years, '+ cast (@months as varchar(2))+' months, '+ cast(@days as varchar(2)) + ' days'
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already found this but no helps. It is taking one static date but I need the data for all patients. With this column I need PatientName, AcctNumber, DOB also. How can I achieve this. Please help me.

Comment: you can create a function with this code and call the function on your select